# Fixed visible tabs/dots TabLayout android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, viewpagerindicator

I have a Custom view with a ViewPager inside and with a TabLayout attached to ViewPager. Bot views are set up to match parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <CarouselPointMarkerViewPager
        android:id="@+id/carousel_point_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/carousel_recycler_padding_start"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/carousel_recycler_padding_end"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout_point"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector_carousel_point"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The TabLayout background is:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/active_point"
          android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/non_active_point"/>

</selector>
```

Example: active_point

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="4dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/bluelight"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And at this moment it works perfect.  I will have a lot of items in the viewpager (cardviews), so what I want is to fix the max visible "dots"(tabs) of the tablayout, but, when user scrolls the view pager the dots have to "move/animate".

At this moment I'm able to make it "move" using the parameter `app:tabMode="scrollable"` .

But I'm not able to "fix" the maximum visible dots at same time to a value.

For example 10 visible dots, but when user scrolls ViewPager, no more dots will appear, but they will animate.

I also tried to give a fixed With to TabLayout, but doesn't work properly, it only just shows 1 .

In next examples, view pager has 61 cardviews:

**Setup to Scrollable Mode:** (in this case it show some dots, and can "slide")

[image]

**Setup to Fixed Mode: (shows the 61 dots)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This in tab layout,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout_point"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector_carousel_point"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="center"    <-- add this line.
    app:tabMode="scrollable"   <-- add this line. 
    app:tabPaddingEnd="4dp"/>
```

Comment: Hi @ShubhamVala , Thanks for your help, this two lines helps me to make it "scrollable"/"slider" dots, but I need also to fix a maximum "dots" visibles, to a value "N"

Comment: try this @Shudy `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(no of page want to show);`